# Strange cache on DNS forward zone

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I have a corporate DNS server using Bind.
I have 3 consul servers. Consul is listening on localhost port 8660 for DNS.
On these servers I have also DNSmasq to forward DNS request from public IP port 53 to Consul on localhost.

The configuration of Consul is very simple. I just activated the DNS port. When I check the DNS locally on port 8660 it is working fine.

The configuration of DNSmasq on each consul server is:

```
server=/subdomain.example.com/127.0.0.1#8600
server=XX.XX.XX.XX (first ip of the corporate DNS)
server=XX.XX.XX.XX (second ip of the corporate DNS)
listen-address=XX.XX.XX.XX (ip of the server)
```

The configuration on the corporate DNS is:

```
zone "subdomain.example.com" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders {
        XX.XX.XX.XX; (ip of the first consul)
        XX.XX.XX.XX; (ip of the second consul)
        XX.XX.XX.XX; (ip of the third consul)
    };
};
```

When some entries are added or removed from consul, the DNS zone on the corporate DNS is updated quite immediately.

When all the entries for a service are deleted from consul, the corporate DNS removed all entries in his table (which is normal).
But if the entries are created again, the DNS from consul is updated but not the corporate DNS.
To update the corporate DNS, I should execute the command `rndc flushtree subdomain.example.com`

Comment: Check the TTL values for the incorrect (cached) entries

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed in the Consul doco, under the title "day 1".  ☺

Set the `soa.min_ttl` configuration option.  Without it, caching DNS proxies do not know how long "no such name" and "no data" information is supposed to last, and you'll get their own best-effort guesses.  This is slightly misrepresented as being the caching DNS proxies' fault.  It isn't.  A "no such name" and "no data" response datagram is supposed to contain TTL information in a (synthesized) SOA resource record.

## Further reading

- https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/security-networking/dns-caching
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard "[The `MINIMUM` field](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/dns-soa-field-semantics.html#Negative)". *The semantics of the fields of an SOA resource record*. Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: But the default value is 0 for min_ttl so .... it should work without it, no ?